# How to frame a rough opening on an existing header?

Tags: walls, windows, framing, studs

I am trying to convert my garage, and the garage door wall has a header on it. I am trying to frame a wall with a rough opening for a window and was wondering how I would fit the king studs, do I build a new header underneath or just have two jack studs?
[image: picture of garage wall]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the window size to some extent, but typically I'd not add another header. In fact, some carpenters put *all* headers against the top plate, with pin studs down to the RO.

Just drop your studs in and build down (if necessary) by whatever means is convenient. You always want at least two members along a door or window for rigidity, curtain backing, etc. Tie it all together well with sheathing and be happy.

Comment: No, no, no. You’ve now transferred as much as 80% of the load from posts with adequate footings (presumably) to an unknown footing (if any).

Comment: No. There won't be enough subsequent sag to do any of that, and if they drive the studs in too tightly the slab may settle a bit (if it isn't fully supported with frost footings, like most modern garages are) and that's the end of it. No skies will fall.

Comment: Saying it won’t be a problem doesn’t mean the existing slab won’t settle with the new load on it. Then you’ll need to deal with a cracked slab. I’d recommend a new beam (probably the size of the existing header) on the new sole plate that spans the existing opening and would support the load from the new posts by the new window. Then, the load is adequately transferred to the ground safely.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a new header or modifying the existing header without accommodating the load transfer to the existing footings will CREATE problems.

I’d add a beam on the sole plate (probably the size of the existing beam) to transfer the load from the header over your new window to your existing footings.

In addition, I’d provide a sealed drip edge at the existing concrete. By code, lumber within 6” of the ground (your driveway) needs to be “treated”.